# alternative to string replace to make function compact

Tags: php

Following is my code, but clearly it is not ideal way to do what i am doing and might slow down site speed.
Please help me understand how i can make this code compact and clean.
Is there any alternative to `str_replace()` in this case.

```html
<?php
  $linkTemp = str_replace("<span class='codeSmall'>", "", $question);
  $linkTemp = str_replace("</span>", "", $linkTemp);
  $linkTemp = str_replace(" ", "-", $linkTemp);
  $linkTemp = str_replace("?", "", $linkTemp);
  $linkTemp = str_replace("'", "", $linkTemp);
  $linkTemp = str_replace('"', "", $linkTemp);
  $linkTemp = str_replace("(", "", $linkTemp);
  $linkTemp = str_replace(")", "", $linkTemp);
  //many similar lines of code
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different ways.  Pick a way that works well for you.

## 1 First way

str_replace works with arrays. Take each line and put the appropriate parts into the appropriate arrays.

For example:

```
$linkTemp = str_replace(" ", "-", $linkTemp);
```

The " " goes into the old array.  The "-" goes into the new array.  The variables don't have to be named new and old.  Name them anything you like.

Another way to do this is break these into simular replacements.  For example everything that will be replaced with a "" can be in one section.  Everything replaced with a "-" in another.  Then do for each loop

```
// for testing
$question = "I like cheese and milk";
$old = array("<span class='codeSmall'>",'</span>',' ','?',"'",'"',"(",")");
$new = array('','','-','',"",'',"","");
$linkTemp = str_replace($old, $new, $question);
echo $linkTemp;
```

## 2 Second way

```
echo "<hr><p>Second way</p>";

$question2 = "I like cheese and milk.  (Do you)?";
$toDashes = array(' ');
foreach ($toDashes as $item) {
    $question2 = str_replace($item, "-", $question2);
}

$toZeroLengthString = array("<span class='codeSmall'>",'</span>','?',"'",'"',"(",")");
foreach ($toZeroLengthString as $item) {
    $question2 = str_replace($item, "", $question2);
}
echo $question2;
```